# form.submit() setting hidden fields = ""

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

Creating hidden fields:

```
Response.Write "<input ID='hdnVendorNumber' NAME='hdnVendorNumber' TYPE='HIDDEN' >"
Response.Write "<input ID='hdnDocumentID' NAME='hdnDocumentID' TYPE='HIDDEN' >"
Response.Write "<input ID='hdnOrderBy' NAME='hdnOrderBy' TYPE='HIDDEN' >"
Response.Write "<input ID='hdnQuerying' NAME='hdnQuerying' TYPE='HIDDEN' >"
```

Function that submits form:

```
function SubmitForm(intOrder)
{

    var form = document.getElementById("frmVendorDocs");

    form.hdnVendorNumber.value="900999";
    form.hdnQuerying.value="True";
    form.hdnDocumentID.value="";
    form.hdnOrderBy.value=intOrder;

    form.submit();
}
```

The problem that I am running into is every time I run a `form.submit()` my hidden fields don't retain the values I set them to but instead get set to "". How can I keep the values I set my hidden fields to every time `form.submit()` is ran?

Comment: Your problem is very unclear. Retain the value over what? When and how you try to access them again?

Answer (score 0):

Don't access the form element from the `form` variable. Get them directly:

```
var vendorNum = document.getElementById("hdnVendorNumber");
vendorNum.value = "True";
```

Or, in one line:

```
document.getElementById("hdnVendorNumber").value = "True";
```

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form the browser leaves the page and loads a new one. Any DOM manipulation you perform will be lost.

Repopulate the fields using the value attributes from server side code.

Answer (score 0):

you didn't specify the input type and you didn't close the tag

Response.Write ""
it should be:
 Response.Write ""

if the error persists try to use Jquery it's easier

Answer (score 0):

load your function 
***SubmitForm***
on body load!